# Flutter firebase Notifications sent from test environment to production environment

Tags: flutter, firebase, notifications, testflight, production-environment

I have a flutter app in TestFlight environment, working properly. When I published that app, there was a problem with push notifications from firebase. Devices used in test environment get this error. When Testflight environment send notification, public app still receive notification via FCM token, how should I handle that?